# How to connect to known devices?

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I want to connect known peripheral device using CBCentralManager. I don't want to scan (using "didDiscover") because ı know peripheral advertising given below advertisingData;

```
let advertisingData = [
        CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: "xxxx",
        CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:[CBUUID(string: "e2c56db5-dffb-48d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0")]
        ] as [String : Any
```

Comment: You have to scan for the peripheral advertising the service at least once. Once you have discovered it and saved the identifier you can use `retrievePeripheralWithIdentifier`

Comment: Thanks. Your commend useful for me @Paulw11